# Camel fetch data from http

Tags: java, apache-camel

Im new to Apache Camel. Im trying to copy this file into a folder: https://www.dnb.no/portalfront/datafiles/miscellaneous/csv/kursliste_ws.xml

I get the error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException:
>   Cannot consume from http endpoint

```
package route;

import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;
import org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator;

public class CurrencyRoute {

        public static void main(String args[])  throws Exception {
            // Log 4j
            BasicConfigurator.configure();

            // Create camel context
            CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();


            // New route
            context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
                public void configure() {
                    from("https://www.dnb.no/portalfront/datafiles/miscellaneous/csv/kursliste_ws.xml")
                            .log("Read file")
                            .to("file:src/main/resources/data/inbox");
                }
            });

            // start the route and let it do its work
            context.start();
            Thread.sleep(10000);

            // stop the CamelContext
            context.stop();


        }

}
```

So I know I have to define a route for it, but where should I define it (in what file??), and how should it be defined?

**Updated code 13.10.2017 13:06**

```
package route;

import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.ProducerTemplate;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;
import org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator;

public class CurrencyRoute {

        public static void main(String args[])  throws Exception {
            // Log 4j
            BasicConfigurator.configure();

            // Create camel context
            CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();

            // Template
            ProducerTemplate template = context.createProducerTemplate();

            // New route
            context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
                public void configure() {
                    from("direct:start").setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("GET"))
                            .to("https://www.dnb.no/portalfront/datafiles/miscellaneous/csv/kursliste_ws.xml")
                            .to("file:src/main/resources/data/inbox/?autoCreate=true");
                }
            });

            // SendBody
            template.sendBody("direct:start", null);

            // start the route and let it do its work

            context.start();
            Thread.sleep(10000);

            // stop the CamelContext
            context.stop();


        }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

For configuring routers in camel you can take a look at excellent examples provided by Camel [here](http://camel.apache.org/examples.html) along with code on github. Also your route is not a valid, firstly the uri endpoint sysntax is wrong, secondly a http or http4 endpoint can only be used as a producer not consumer.

> You can only produce to endpoints generated by the HTTP component.
>   Therefore it should never be used as input into your camel Routes.

For your case take a look [here](http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Using-CamelHttpComponent-to-download-file-td478611.html). Basically you need to do something like this

```
from("direct:start").setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("GET")) 
.to("https://www.dnb.no/portalfront/datafiles/miscellaneous/csv/kursliste_ws.xml")
.to("file:src/main/resources/data/inbox/?autoCreate=true");
```

and then call the direct endpoint

```
template.sendBody("direct:start", null);
```

or you may make use of a timer as explained [here](http://camel.apache.org/timer.html) and your route as something like this

```
from(timer).to(http).to(file);
```

Comment: I dont have any variables named "template". Did you mean context.sendBody("direct:start", null); ?

Comment: You can create a simple ProducerTemplate using ProducerTemplate template = context.createProducerTemplate();

Comment: I updated the code with template (see my first post) then I got this error:
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[Message: [Body is null]]

Comment: Set the body to some dummy string. Then you inside the route you can clear the body. The string is just to trigger the route. In any case I suggest you don't put your route code in your main method. Have a seperate RouteBuilder class for this. There are many examples online that show this.